# Displaying WebDings font in Java swing isn't working, shown glyphs are empty

Tags: java, swing, fonts, java-font

The code is:

```
package ssl;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class WebDingsPhontGlyph extends JFrame {

    public WebDingsPhontGlyph() {
        setTitle("WebDings Phone Glyph");
        setSize(200, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setFont(new Font("Webdings", Font.PLAIN, 50));
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.drawString("^", 50, 100); // Phone glyph
                g2d.drawString("É", 100, 100); // Messaging glyph
            }
        };

        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            WebDingsPhontGlyph webDingsPhoneGlyph = new WebDingsPhontGlyph();
            webDingsPhoneGlyph.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

and the JPanel view is, despite of I expect specific WebDings glyphs.

[image]

If I use another font name, that definitely doesn't exits, like

```
g2d.setFont(new Font("webdings33", Font.PLAIN, 50));
```

it uses Arial font and shows the glyps.

[image]

I have Webdings installed:

```
String [] fonts = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
                for (String fontname: fonts) {
                    System.out.println(fontname);
                }
```

outputs among others

```
Trebuchet MS
TypoUpright BT
Verdana
Webdings
Wingdings
Wingdings 2
Wingdings 3
Yu Gothic
```

UPD.

I'm trying to test the metadata:

```
 Font webdingsFont = new Font("WebDings", Font.PLAIN, 12);
                System.out.println(webdingsFont.isBold());
                System.out.println(webdingsFont.isItalic());
                System.out.println(webdingsFont.isTransformed());
                System.out.println(webdingsFont.isPlain());
                System.out.println(webdingsFont.getNumGlyphs());
                System.out.println(webdingsFont.getStyle());
                System.out.println(webdingsFont.getFamily());

                for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
                    if (webdingsFont.canDisplay((char) i)) {
//                        g2d.drawString(Character.toString((char) i), 50, i*12); // Display the glyph at a specific position
                        System.out.println(i+" "+Character.toString((char) i));
                    }
                }
```

and I'm getting the ouptut not of the `Webdings`, but `Wingdings` font!

false
false
false
true
227
0
Webdings
9
10

13
8204 ‌
8205 ‍
61472 
61473 
61474 
61475 

and if I try to load a real Wingdings, I get exactly the same output and visible behavior. So, it looks like Wingdings is installed as a Webdings at least in my windows version.

[image]

Comment: Please check the answers in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7461132/), including how to check if the font of interest exists on that computer and how to install it if it doesn't.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i see this font installed on Windows locally and able to select gyphs through the Character Map

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this font is here. May be the issue that is doesn't have Font.PLAIN or specific size or what else?

Comment: The Windows Character Map is lying in order to be “helpful” (ironically, it is doing the opposite).  The characters are not at ASCII codepoints at all.  Wingdings and Webdings generally place their characters in the Unicode Private Use Area starting at U+F020.  Add 0xf000 to each character to get its true position in the font.  For example, instead of `"^"`, use `String.format("%c", '^' + 0xf000)`.  Instead of `"É"`, use `String.format("%c", 'É' + 0xf000)`.

Comment: @VGR this was really helpfull!! Please post your answer as the official one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Character Map is lying in order to be “helpful.”  (Ironically, it is doing the opposite.)

The characters are not at ASCII codepoints at all.  Wingdings and Webdings generally place their characters in the [Unicode Private Use Area](https://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html) starting at U+F020.  Add 0xf000 to each character to get its true position in the font.

For example, instead of `"^"`, use `String.format("%c", '^' + 0xf000)`.  Instead of `"É"`, use `String.format("%c", 'É' + 0xf000)`.

Of course, one can also write `"\uf05e"` and `"\uf0c9"`. I find using String.format and adding 0xf000 a little easier to understand and maintain.